# showing a table as is without any tab_stat_*()

Tags: r, expss

As I am using expss to summarize my tables, I would like all other tables to look in the similar styling. So basically I have a dplyr summarized data frame and now I want to make it nicely formatted and labelled as expss style. This means I would not like to use any `tab_stat_*()` or say **use a summarized table as is**.  Is this possible? So something like

```r
dplyr_summary %>%
    expss::tab_rows(column1) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(column2) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(column3) %>%
    expss::tab_stat(NULL) %>%
    expss::tab_pivot()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tab_stat_fun(identity)` should work:

```
dplyr_summary %>%
    expss::tab_rows(column1) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(column2) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(column3) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_fun(identity) %>%
    expss::tab_pivot()
```

You can also try `as.etable` function. It is suited for simple cases when you already have columns and rows labels and there is no need to reposition rows to column names.